# Searching for string in PE file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.7 to overwrite some data in a resource section of a PE file. The resource section string table has a string with 1024 A's. When I open it in a hex editor I see all the A's..

```
00 00 28 08 41 00 41 00 41 00 41 00 41 00 41 00 41 00 41 00 41 00 41 00
```

I use this to find the A's in the file.

```
if b'\x00A'*1024 in file:
    s=file.replace(b'\x00A'*1024, message)
```

However this ends up failing. If I change 1024 to 1023 it works but ends up leaving a "A" at the beginning of the string table. So if I wanted to overwrite all the A's with B's it would end up as..

```
ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB...
```

I am sure it is because I am only searching for 1023 and it is leaving a A behind. But I am just not sure why it would not find it. I have copied the hex of the A's and it contains 1024 41's and 1024 00's so it is all there.

UPDATE:
Changed the if statement to:

```
if b'A' + b'\x00A'*2087 in file:
```

And it seems like it found the first A.
Credits to @Kevin

Comment: The first A comes before the first `\x00`, so it does not match.

Comment: I updated my first post. Seems like that was the issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kevin Please put your answer in the answer section so this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence of bytes in the PE file begins with `A\x00`, but you're searching for `\x00A`, so the first A does not match.  Change your test string to `b'A\x00'*1024`.